# How to send response in html file? (Node.js, html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, request, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert html (which I got by sending a POST request to one website) to png in Node.js

The POST request seems to be working fine as I get the response html code

The html2canvas library seemed to be just the solution, but since it doesn't work in Node.js, I've tried creating a html document and sending a GET request to it with html param `<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>`, but I just got a response with it's source html code:

```
<html><head>
    <script src="scripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function(){
            var urlp = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            var b = new DOMParser().parseFromString(urlp.get("html"), "text/html").body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = b;
            html2canvas(document.body).then(canvas => {
                new Response(canvas.toDataURL());
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

Is there a way to send a response in html?
Or maybe another way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)? It can take pictures of websites or plain html

Comment: This doesn't make sense. HTML documents are not web servers. You can't send requests to them and they can't make responses.

Comment: I don't think puppeteer would work since I'm sending a post request with formData and puppeteer uses .goto(url), I'd also need to save the base64 image url for later use

Comment: You would do something like this: `await page.goto(\`data:text/html,<html><h3>Hello world!</h3><img src="http://localhost:3000/logo.jpg"></html>\`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });`

Comment: Yeah! That might just work! I'll just have to get data url from a locally saved screenshot.

Comment: Quentin, would there be a way to do it with a web server?